# Using Framework7 $f7.router.navigate in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, html-framework-7

#### Objective

I'm trying to change a Framework 7 route in Vuex.

Something like this

```
actions: {
  login (context, payload) {
    fetch(...POST Request).then( res => {
      if(res.success === 1){
        $f7.router.navigate('...Some Route')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### Issue

$f7 does not exist in the store. $f7 is defined in on the instance of the Framework 7 and attached to the Vue.prototype. You can then access $f7 via each component with this.$f7. You can see this in the code on [line 23](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-vue/blob/master/src/vue-plugin.js)

The only way I have been able to get the variable is by exporting my Vue app object and then importing it in the store and then getting access to the instance like the following.

#### Vue App

```js
export default new Vue({
  ...
})
```

#### Store

```js
import vue from './app'

vue.$f7.router.navigate('some route'))
```

This works but what is best practice here?

Comment: Hi have you found any solution to this? I have the same problem, but exporting the Vue app does not works for me. I am trying to access F7 router in Vuex action

Comment: I did not find an alternative solution. If anything put a bounty on this question and see what other people say.

Answer (score 0):

how about this code.

```js
this.$f7router.navigate('/somewhere/');
```